# Is there a way to authentize user using Google account without being remembered permanently?

Tags: javascript, html, logout, google-oauth

In my Angular app, I am using Google oAuth2. It works fine. Problem is that the user remains logged in his Google account forever.

This is a possible security problem for users using my app on public computers. (They log out from the app, but not from G. account)

I am using a known workaround to log out the user from Google account by request to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en
But it's a hack, it doesn't work in Chrome and it's annoying for users using personal devices.

Ideal flow is: User is logged in his G. account already -> authenticated. User is not logged in - ask login, authenticate but don't log in to G. account.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Comment: What if the person want to stay signed in? you don't have control over Google sign in part during OAuth, and you shouldn't do the hack you described. If the user uses a public computer he should use private session / clear the cookies or directly ask to logout on Google domain. Google even removed the "remember me" checkbox during the login flow for that reason.